# What is the angle of a point?

Tags: angle

I had a question in my test:
"The sum of angles at a point is________. (A) 0; (B) 360; (C) 90; (D) 180;"
I feel that since there are no angles or rays drawn at the point in the first place, the answer *can't* be 360, but that is the correct answer for this question. How is this possible?

Comment: +1 since you are right to be confused. Its a vague and lazily formulated question.

Comment: I'd complain to whoever wrote that question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the question must be that if you *do* draw some rays from your point and add up all of the angles between neighboring rays, then the sum will be 360° -- no matter how many rays or their directions.

Answer (score 1):

This a perfect example of a stupid question, for following reasons

1.The question is ambiguous : all and any answer given to this question can be justified to be correct or wrong.

2.it serves no purpose but to give the impression of there is a correct answer to awarded with points. A sad case of education being reduced to teachers discretion with/out in/proper justification.

Nobody should waste time on nonsense like this question or similar type of questions, e.g. given n numbers what is the next number, or given n pictures what is the next correct picture.

Note : this answer is just as stupid as the question, and many points for or against it can be pointed out.

Btw , is the point also a circle? can the points of boundary be inside the circle on the centre? or is the point an sphere? on the sphere we can draw triangles with angles greater than 270, so the angle of the point is the sum of the angles of the triangles  on the sphere of diameter 0.

the point can also be a triangle, square or hexagon of size 0, having 180, 360 or more angles or less angles.